# Hibernate is creating less tables than specified in informix database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, informix

I am using informix database version 11.5 and I am trying to create tables in it using hibernate.Whenever I start the application, not all tables are created in the database instead only a few of them are created. I have created entity classes for all of it.
Note: This is working properly with MYSQL database.

Comment: Java sources, logs.

Comment: @JacekCz I am not getting any error. I am using hibernate dialect for informix here and added maven dependency for the same.

Comment: You should be planning   to move from Informix 11.50 to 12.10.  That's probably not the solution to your problem but the support left is limited.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using Informix Dynamic server 11.5 here. Do you mean to say that the problem I am facing here would not be there with 12.10?

Comment: No; I explicitly said it is probably not the solution to your problem.  However, 11.50 was released a while ago and only has limited time left with support so you should be planning to upgrade soon.

Comment: sql logs (running from hibernate, turn option on) seems the most important and source of controversial Javas. Personally i DONT BELIVE in hidden problem between two professional envinroments

Comment: I can see in the logs that SQL query for each table is being fired but not all tables are created. I noticed something weird in the logs, after creating tables, hibernate is firing drop query for all the tables then it is firing create query for them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, I had given column definition in one of my entities and it was not supported in Informix. Hence it was not creating those tables.